# How do I prevent types and properties from my Entity Model to be persisted to the database?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I created an MVC project that uses entity framework to create the database. I have 2 models that each have about 5 fields. However, I want some of these fields to have a unique return type that I create myself, but I don't want the the unique data-types to be made into tables.

***EDIT***

Per the comments: just to clarify, I still would like the Person and Occupation table to have Kids and Address data under the appropriate sections

for example:

Models:

```
class Person {
 [Key]
 public int PersonID{get;set}
 public string name {get;set;}
 public int age {get;set;}
 //note below: return type is ICollection of type Kids
 //or it can just be a return type of type Kids like so
 //public Kids kids {get;set;}
 public ICollection<Kids> kids {get;set;}
 public int OccupationID{get;set;}
 public virtual Occupation Occupation {get;set}
}

class Occupation {
 [Key]
 public int OccupationID{get;set;}
 public string OccupationName{get;set}
 //note the line below has a return type of Address
 public Address Location{get;set;}
 public int PersonID{get;set;}
 public virtual Person Person{get;set;}

}
```

other data types used above

```
class Kids {
 public int numberOfKids{get;set;}
 public List<string> namesOfKids{get;set;}
}

class Address {
 public string street{get;set;}
 public string city{get;set;}
 public int apartmentNumber{get;set;}
}
```

if I don't want the `Kids` and the `Address` data-types to be made into database tables, where would these be placed in the project? I ask this because I tried making a new folder called "src" and put them in that folder, but when I tried to create a new scaffolded item for the Person model, I got an error saying these datatypes don't have a key.

Another question: I know I'm asking how to not make these data types into tables, but is that a bad practice? should I also make them into tables or not?

also: can I have multiple virtual fields? or does that break something?

I really appreciate the help

Comment: So you don't want these fields stored in the DB at all?  If so, you can use the `[NotMapped]` annotation for this

Comment: @Thewads thank you, will try! where does the annotation go? before the class declaration or inside?

Comment: It's still asking for a key, I put the annotation right above the class declaration

Comment: You need to put it above the field, not the class declaration.  I will add an answer to illustrate

Comment: Perhaps instead of the data not existing in the database, you would like the properties of `Kids` and `Address` to be stored as fields in the `Person` and `Occupation` tables?

Comment: I think this is a bit more complex than [NotMapped] because I assume you still want addresses and kids information to be stored in the database, don't you?

Comment: Bingo! @KeithPayne and GertArnold I still want those values in the database under the person/occupation tables

Comment: Then how should a `Kid` be stored, in the `Person` table? `Address` can be a "complex type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are wanting to achieve is to have certain class fields not get created in the database, then you can make use of the `[NotMapped]` data annotation

```
class Occupation {
    [Key]
    public int OccupationID{get;set;}
    public string OccupationName{get;set}

    [NotMapped]
    public Address Location{get;set;}
    public int PersonID{get;set;}
    public virtual Person Person{get;set;}
}
```

In the above scenario, when creating your DB structure, and when querying your database, the field under the `[NotMapped]` attribute will be ignored.

Can read more about the class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

As well as this, do not include any class in your DbContext which you do not wish to create tables for

Also, as far as your `can I have multiple virtual fields? or does that break something?` goes:

`virtual` properties in entity framework are primarily used for allowing lazy loading, if you have it configured in your system.

It is also however has an effect on change tracking. If you're using pure POCOs or are using proxies but don't make the properties virtual, then change detection becomes more involved. You can read about that in more detail here: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a class to be mapped, just don't include it in the `DbContext` class as a `DbSet<T>`.

if, inside a class, you don't want a property to be mapped, you can either use a `NotMapped` attribute in the property, or, if you are using fluent api, you can do something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Ignore(p => p.LastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use an interface to shape the class the way you want it and to compose the complex objects in the getters:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string name {get;set;}
    int age {get;set;}
    Kids kids {get;}
    Occupation Occupation {get;}
    void AddKid(string name);
}

public class Person : IPerson 
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID{get;set}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int age {get;set;}
    [NotMapped]
    public Kids kids { get
        {
            Kids k = new Kids
            {
                namesOfKids = (new [] 
                {
                    Name1,
                    Name2,
                    Name3,
                    // ...
                }).Where(n => n != null).ToList();
            };
            k.numberOfKids = k.namesOfKids.Count;
            return k;
        }
    }

    public int numberOfKids{get; set;}
    public List<string> namesOfKids{get; set;}

    public int OccupationID{get;set;}
    [NotMapped]
    public Occupation Occupation {get { // TODO }}
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    // ... Add more name fields up to the max

    public void AddKid(string name)
    {
        switch (numberOfKids)
        {
            case 0: Name1 = name;
                    break;
            case 1: Name2 = name;
                    break;
            // ...

        }
        numberOfKids ++;
    }
}

class Kids 
{
    public int numberOfKids{get;set;}
    public List<string> namesOfKids{get;set;}
}
```

The caveat is that you will only use `IPerson` objects in your code. You can direct cast any `Person` object to `IPerson`.

This isn't compiled or tested, but it should give the idea of how to accomplish your goal.